# how to call jquery addclass() method after response is returned?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, tabs, response

I have a jsp page which has `3 tabs`. The name of file containing tabs is `Tabexp.jsp` So initially first tab is highlighted as,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    checkalert();
//Default Action
   $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
   $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
   $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
 });
```

this is fine.

When I am in 3rd tab, it has a table , table has some context menus.

If select any one of context menu it will request the `servlet`.

Servlet does all operation and send respose through `RequestDispather` to `Tabexp.jsp`.

So the problem is, when response has send back to `Tabexp.jsp` the first tab is highlighted but I want to show 3rd tab after the response sent.

What I planned is, I set a request parameter in servlet as

```
 request.setParameter("success","success");
```

using this parameter value I want to call jquery `addClass()` method.

But I am not able to do this . can any one help me in this please. It would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Get the request attribute in `scriptlet` . according to the value of request attribute add the jquery class,

Here is the code ,

```
 <%
 String succmsg=(String)request.getAttribute("success");
  if(succmsg!=null)
  {
 %>
   $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
   $("ul.tabs li:last").addClass("active").show(); //Activate last tab
   $(".tab_content:last").show(); //Show last tab content
 <%
  }else{
 %>
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
 <%
  }
 %>
```